Probability that coin will lie in one strip
We drop a coin onto a floor made of parallel strips of wood to see whether the coin
would land entirely within the boundaries of a single strip. The diameter of the coin
is 24mm and each wooden strip is of 6cm width.
a. Design a suitable sample space for this experiment;
b. Find the probability of the event that the coin will land entirely within the boundaries of a single strip
My work.
Here we need to model this problem using center of the coin. So our sample space will be if distance between center of the point of the coin and near strip is between 12 and 30 then the coin will land entirely within boundaries of single strip. And so probability that it will line in one strip will be $$ 18/30$$
Is my thinking right?
Question that I have with this method is that we are sort of ignoring rational and irrational numbers between integers.

The sample space is the set of all possible outcomes.
If an outcome is designated as the distance between the center of the coin and the nearest edge of the strip on which it lands, then your sample space is $[0,30]$ mm.
The event of landing entirely between the edges, is the set of outcomes $(12,30]$ mm.
Note: these are theoretically real numbers measured in millimetres.  Although, practically, there are limitations on the resolution of measurement.
The probability of this event depends on the probability distribution, which  you've reasonably decided to be a Uniform Continuous distribution.  Thus evaluating the probability as:$$\dfrac{30-12}{30-0}=\dfrac{3}{5}$$
